# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Object[]

Tags: java, android

In my android project, I want to create a generic class to store all types of entities in sharedPreferences but give the error :

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Object[]`

here is my code :

```
public ArrayList<E> getItems(Context context) {
        android.content.SharedPreferences settings;
        List<E> objects ;
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (settings.contains(ITEM_NAME)) {
            String json = settings.getString(ITEM_NAME, null);
            GsonBuilder gson = new GsonBuilder();
            Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<E>>(){}.getType();

            E[] items = gson.create().fromJson(json,
                    collectionType);  // in this line occurs error


            objects = new ArrayList<E>(Arrays.asList(items));
        } else
            return null;

        return (ArrayList<E>) objects;
    }
```

Comment: The error says it all. You are trying to cast a `ArrayList[]` to an `Object[]`.

Comment: In other words you already had an `ArrayList`, as you could have discovered from the Javadoc, and also more or less exactly as you asked for when you specified `collectionType`. No need to create another one.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
List<E> items = gson.create().fromJson(json, collectionType);
```

That exception is complaining that you had an ArrayList object (which was returned from `fromJson()`), but you attempted to cast it to an array with that assignment to `E[] items`.